# Removing Street Suffix from Address

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to identify(and Remove) street suffixes (like "St", "Dr", etc...) from addresses.  Assume that the suffixes are uniform and that we can create a comprehensive list of them.

Thanks!

```
 street_suffix_list = ["St", "Dr", "Ave", "Blvd", "Tr"]
 address = "105 Main St"

 #returns "Main St"
 street = address.gsub(/^((\d[a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z])*/, '')

 #desired: "St"
 street_suffix = 

 #desired: "Main"
 street_name =
```

Comment: You forgot to write a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to separate street from suffix with `Regexp`:

```
street_suffix_list = ["St", "Dr", "Ave", "Blvd", "Tr"]
address = "105 Main St"

idx = /(#{street_suffix_list.join('|')})\z/ =~ address
# $1 => St
sfx = $1
street = address[0..idx-1].strip
# street => "105 Main"
```

It is better to use safe join method for suffix array with [`Regexp` `::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) method (thanx @Jordan):

```
idx = /\b(#{Regexp.union(street_suffix_list)})\z/ =~ address
```

Comment: Are you sure the words should all be at the end of the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew since he said that it is *suffix*, yes

Comment: Yeah, but suffix is not the ending. That is why I thought a word boundary could be a better fit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew > In linguistics, a suffix (also sometimes termed postfix or ending) is an affix which is placed after the stem of a word. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix

Comment: We come from different schools. In Russian, suffix does not have to be the *case ending*. A case ending is considered to be [окончание](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ending). Suffixes are a bit  different thing (postfixes are really like suffixes though).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know, I am  russian =)

Comment: The street suffix is always at the end, at least for US addresses.  Of course this isn't true if you have the entire address with the state/zip, but for my data I just have the street.

Comment: Don't do `arr.join("|")` in a Regexp (unless you want the strings in `arr` to be treated as regular expressions). This is what `Regexp.union` is for: `/\b#{Regexp.union(street_suffix_list)}\z/`

Answer (score 3):

Using the 'streetaddress' gem, you can parse any address and
extract components of the address.

```
gem install StreetAddress
irb
1.9.3-p551 :002 > require 'street_address'
 => true 
1.9.3-p551 :003 > address = StreetAddress::US.parse("1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC, 20500")
 => 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC 20500 
1.9.3-p551 :004 > address.street
 => "Pennsylvania" 
1.9.3-p551 :005 >
```

Comment: Can you also get the 'Ave' with that gem?

Comment: I didnt dig deep in to the documentation, but my idea was to subtract the street() to get the "Ave"

Comment: Just trying to do it without a gem first, but if there are problems I'll probably resort to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dynamic regex pattern with alternations (also matching optional dots at the end to remove that punctuation, too, if present):

```
/\b(?:St|Dr|Ave|Blvd|Tr)\b\.*/
```

See [this regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/GjbnniLVqe)

Here is sample [Ruby code](https://ideone.com/CJEt3W):

```
street_suffix_list = ["St", "Dr", "Ave", "Blvd", "Tr"]
address = "105 Main St"
puts address.gsub(/\b(?:#{street_suffix_list.join("|")})\b\.*/, "").strip
# => 105 Main
```

**NOTE that without word boundaries, you will remove `Tr` in `Transylvania` and similar.**

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the position of the suffix will be the last word in the string, then you don't need regexes to do it:

```
2.3.0 :017 > suffixes = %w(st ave dr rd blvd)
 => ["st", "ave", "dr", "rd", "blvd"]
2.3.0 :018 > address = '105 Main St'
 => "105 Main St"
2.3.0 :019 > tokens = address.split
 => ["105", "Main", "St"]
2.3.0 :021 > found_match = suffixes.include?(tokens.last.downcase)
 => true
2.3.0 :028 > if found_match
2.3.0 :029?>   street_suffix = tokens.last
2.3.0 :030?>   street_rest = tokens[0..-2]
2.3.0 :031?>   # ...
2.3.0 :032 >     puts street_suffix; puts street_rest.join(' ')
2.3.0 :033?>   end
St
105 Main
 => nil
```

That all said, you will have a really hard time accounting for all the variations that addresses can contain.  I strongly suggest using a gem for this, possibly the `StreetAddress` gem mentioned by @oystersauce8.